What does w.r.t. mean? I've found it in the summary of jup365.bsp
Inside summary of the file jup365.bsp I have found this:
Summary for: jup365.bsp
 
Bodies: EARTH BARYCENTER (3) w.r.t. SOLAR SYSTEM BARYCENTER (0)
        JUPITER BARYCENTER (5) w.r.t. SOLAR SYSTEM BARYCENTER (0)
        SUN (10) w.r.t. SOLAR SYSTEM BARYCENTER (0)
        EARTH (399) w.r.t. EARTH BARYCENTER (3)
        IO (501) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        EUROPA (502) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        GANYMEDE (503) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        CALLISTO (504) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        AMALTHEA (505) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        THEBE (514) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        ADRASTEA (515) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        METIS (516) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        JUPITER (599) w.r.t. JUPITER BARYCENTER (5)
        Start of Interval (ET)              End of Interval (ET)
        -----------------------------       -----------------------------
        1600 JAN 10 00:00:00.000            2200 JAN 10 00:00:00.000

What does w.r.t. mean?

"With respect to",  in the sense of "relative to."  for example, "Earth Barycenter relative to the Solar System Barycenter."

I'm not going to vote on this question either way, but I don't see much relation to Space Exploration here. It seems to be a straight-forward English language comprehension question.

Seems relevant to me as it could have been a technical term. (It wasn't, but the questioner didn't know that.)

I agree with @GordonD; astronomy and space explanation uses a lot of terminology and acronyms. This could easily have had 'SSB' as the abbreviation, instead of the spelled-out Solar System Barycenter, which is definitely not a straight-forward English language problem

Did you google "what does 'w.r.t.' mean?" The answer pops up immediately. It means either "with respect to" or "with regard to". I'm voting to close as having nothing to do with space science.

I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing whatsoever to do with space exploration.

agree, no prior research

@astrosnapper I have searched about the term before ask it here. I'm not English, and I thought that the best place this question was here. 'SSB' is an abbreviation than only astronomers could understand.

@DavidHammen What does "with respect to" or "with regard to" mean in this context? Do you think only knowing the meaning of the abbreviation I'm going to understand it? I'm not an astronomer or physics. Because you already understand it, it's all very simple for you.

"w.r.t." or just "wrt" is a common abbreviation for "with respect to" or "with regard to". It's not a special astronomy jargon term or anything.

I think it is. What does w.r.t. mean in this context? Will I get the ephemeris of Europa with respect to Jupiter? Is the ID of Europa with respect to Jupiter? Will Europa have another ID with respect to the Sun?

Where the "w.r.t" matters in the space context is the use in e.g. Spice SPKGEO to generate positions of one of Jupiter's moons relative to an near-Earth or on-Earth observer. SPKGEO computes the positions relative to a common center of motion and Spice needs ephemeris files that can produce the chains of 'position of X w.r.t Y' needed. So the moon e.g. Io wrt to Jupiter's barycenter, Jupiter's barycenter wrt to the SSB, the Earth relative to the Earth-Moon barycenter (EMB) and the EMB relative to the SSB are all needed

The first half of the SPK tutorial document gives a pretty good basis of how to understand their particular form of ephemeris data.
https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/Tutorials/pdf/individual_docs/18_spk.pdf

@VansFannel It is absolutely not a special astronomy term: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/what-does-wrt-mean
